# Cannot define category for undefined class

Tags: objective-c, chromium, xcode8

I'm currently trying to compile chromium in XCode 8 and am now on the Mac specific parts. Unfortunately, I get a compiler error for this header: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/52.0.2743.82/base/mac/sdk_forward_declarations.h, because for multiple classes this file contains only a forward declaration and then a category definition. For instance search for "CBPeripheral".

I can reproduce this problem in another project simply by adding this to an obj-c header file:

```
@class Test;

@interface Test (Blah) {
}
@end
```

I don't understand how the chromium header can compile, but obviously it does. So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is a new "feature" of XCode 8. The code compiles fine in XCode 7.

Answer (score 1):

iMac:src $ vi base/mac/sdk_forward_declarations.h

Add these two lines below to compile:

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CBPeripheral.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CBUUID.h>
```

Comment: I wonder how this can solve the issue given that I can reproduce it with a simple test case independent on the original headers.

Comment: That can't help in this case I think